# Adding text on product page is more that 0 in Opencart

Tags: php, opencart

I would like to add a line of text below the stock status on the Opencart product page. I thought a simple PHP If Then would do the trick but sadly I must be doing it wrong. Could someone help me out?

Thanks!

```
<?php
if ($text_stock > 0)
  echo "If ordered before 5pm this product ships same day";
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using

```
if ($product_info['quantity'] > 0) {
```

Instead. That is the data pulled directly from the database

Comment: Thanks Sir. That did the trick. After I posted this I realized that $text_stock was the text "Availability" so I was way off.